# AEM 6.5.8 doesn't minify our client library javascript

Tags: javascript, gcc, aem, minify

on AEM system/console/configMgr, I turned on the minify option, and on my client library folder, I put jsProcessor=[min:gcc;obfuscate=true;languageIn=ECMASCRIPT_2019;languageOut=ECMASCRIPT3;compilationLevel=advanced]

Still, I see all other javscripts is minified. my client library file name has .min.js, but the content is still original javascript content.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the clientlibs and see the logs when the time comes for minifying your clientlib:

http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.rebuild.html